# On the etymology of “discipulus” and “disciplina”

Tags: etymology, reference-request

I am interested in the origin of the words *discipulus* and *disciplina,* which have found their way into many modern languages, e.g., in the English words *disciple* and *discipline.* Unfortunately, there seem to be two conflicting etymologies, which I detail below. I am asking for some authorative information that goes beyond what is described below, in particular any arguments for and against these etymologies.

#### Etymology 1

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=disciple) gives as one alternative for the origin of the English *disciple:*

> Old English *discipul* […], Biblical borrowing from Latin *discipulus* "pupil, student, follower," said to be from *discere* "to learn" [OED, Watkins], […]

A similar derivation is claimed by [the Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discipulus#Latin) and some other sources (which may however all be copying each other).

#### Etymology 2

The German etymological dictionary Kluge (23<sup>rd</sup> edition, 1999) gives the following chain of origin (for the German *Disziplin*):

- *Disziplin* comes from *disciplina.*
- *disciplina* comes from *discipulus.*
- *discipulus* comes from *discipere,* where the latter is marked as a deduced form (“erschlossen”) and shall mean *to grap* (“[erfassen](http://www.dict.cc/?s=erfassen)”).
- *discipere* is formed from *dis* and capere.*

As sources it cites:

- H. Schulz, *Deutsches Fremdwörterbuch* (1913), 151.
- O. Mauck – *Der lateinische Begriff ‘disciplina’* (Diss. Freiburg/Schweiz 1941) [*Diss.* means *Dissertation* and refers to a PhD thesis or similar.]
- Joachim Ritter – Historisches Wörterbuch der Philosophie 2 (1972), 256–261
- Lexikon des Mittelalters (1986), 1130

I have access to neither of those and suspect that only the second item will provide further insights.

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=disciple) gives a similar account as an alternative to Etymology 1:

> But according to Barnhart and Klein, from a lost compound **discipere* "to grasp intellectually, analyze thoroughly," from *dis-* "apart" […] + *capere* "to take, take hold of" […]

#### Background

The reason why I am so interested in this is the spelling of the German word *Disziplin* in orthographies that feature a [long s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) (ſ):

- If the letter *s* in that word would originate from an *s* at the end of a (non-inflectionary) morpheme, as in Etymology 2, the word would be spelt ***Disziplin***.
- If the letter *s* was originating from an *s* in the beginning or middle of a morpheme, as in Etymology 1, the word would be spelt ***Diſziplin***. This is the spelling given by old German dictionaries, but this may be just a reflection of the etymological knowledge of that time.

Comment: To my knowledge, the pre-1910 spelling of the German word is not Diſziplin, but Disciplin, e.g. here, 4 lines from the bottom: http://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/view/haeckel_weltraethsel_1899?p=45

Comment: @fdb: That you find examples with *s* instead of *ſ* does not surprise me and happened often in these borderline cases. Nonetheless, my three dictionaries from the beginning of the 20th century all give *Diſziplin.* The change from *c* to *z* happened [around the beginning of the 20th century](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Disziplin%2CDisciplin&corpus=20) and was in accordance with a general change of “Germanising” *c*s (e.g., *Concern* to *Konzern).*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

De Vaan (2008) says that the etymology is uncertain and that both of the theories you mentioned have problems. He bases this on the two most commonly consulted etymological dictionaries of Latin, Walde–Hoffmann and Ernout–Meillet:

> Proto-Italic **kapelo-* 'who takes'.
>
> Walde–Hoffmann derive *discipulus* from **dis-capiō* 'to assume mentally, interpret' (cf. *disceptāre* 'to negotiate, decide' Cic.+), which is semantically not compelling. Ernout–Meillet are very hesitant about it. On the other hand, *-pulus* is difficult to explain on the basis of *discō*.
>
> Bibliography: Walde–Hoffmann I: 355; Ernout–Meillet 176. → *capiō*